# How do I check is two conditions are true without writing the same condition twice

Tags: c++

This is a rather simple question I believe, I simply want to know how to write this more efficiently;
I have a pHandle to a process that works fine. However, when I was writing out my error check I realized that if I write

```
if (pHandle == NULL || INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

It will always be true even if the pHandle is valid. I believe this is because INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE will always return true since it's not being checked against anything on the right side. So I wrote it out like this and it started working again.

```
if (pHandle == NULL || pHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

My question is, how do I write my check to make sure pHandle is not equal to NULL or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE in an if statement without writing pHandle twice?

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: You just write it out twice. That's how boolean logic works in C++.

Comment: But it's *not* "the same condition". It's true that you use `pHandle` twice, and do a comparison for equality twice, but it's still two different comparisons.

Comment: If you're looking to avoid repetitive code, you could put an inline-function like this into one of your header-files:  `inline bool IsHandleInvalid(HANDLE pHandle) {return ((pHandle==NULL)||(pHandle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE));}` ... then just call that whenever you need to.  (It won't be more runtime-efficient than doing the two checks manually, but it won't be any less runtime-efficient either, and it will ensure that your checking is done correctly and consistently at all call sites)

Comment: *"INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE will always return true since it's not being checked against anything"*. Look at the value of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Is it equivalent to zero/false ? It isn't; thus why it is equivalent to always-true.

Comment: Technically, you could `switch((intptr_t)pHandle)` but that's even uglier than the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach here is to write that out twice. If you want someone to blame, blame C where this restriction is inherited from.

This is largely a product of how C is just "fancy assembler", and in assembly terms your code looks like:

```
LOAD a, pHandle ;; Load handle into register A
LOAD b, NULL ;; Load NULL into b
CMP a, b ;; Compare a and b
JEQ INNER ;; Test succeeds, so short-circuit to interior "jump if equal"
LOAD b, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ;; Load NULL into b
CMP a, b ;; Compare a and b
JNE ENDIF ;; Test fails, so short-circuit exit via "jump not equal"
INNER: ... ;; Interior of if code
ENDIF: ... ;; Outside of if
```

As there's no CPU instruction for "compare this thing to one or more other things", only a "compare this to that", you're stuck repeating yourself.

The primary reason there's no "compare to multiple" instructions is because a register can hold only one value at a time, there's usually no "array registers", as in can hold an arbitrary list of values. Every operation is defined in terms of one or more registers each holding a single value.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I appreciate it a lot. Sucks that there is no way to compare two things at once, but I'm glad I at least now know I can't.